# server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): mean stack & ionic

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, mean-stack

I making a request to the back-end server of the port number `8000`. I'm making request from the android emulator. so, instead of `localhost` i'm using ip address. It is throwing the error as

> Failed to load resource: the
>   http://192.168.0.102:8000/api/facebookuser server responded with a
>   status of 404 (Not Found)

This is my code

```
postFacebookData(userdata) {
  alert(userdata);
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  return this.http.post('http://192.168.0.102:8000/api/facebookuser',userdata,{headers: headers})

}
```

This is from routes file

```
 router.post('/facebookuser', function(req,res) {
  console.log('facebook request');
```

It is not subscribing to the method

```
this.fbPage.postFacebookData(userData)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          if (data.success) {
            alert('Data added sucessfully ' && data.msg);
            this.authservices.storeUserData(data.token,data.user);
            this.navCtrl.push(EditinfoPage);
          }
          else {
            alert('data is not added');
          }
        },(err) => {
          alert('error in subscribing ' + err);
```

I'm getting an error message in the cosole from the above code as

> error in subscribing [object object]

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating, that the request cannot find the resource you are trying to request.

1. Make sure that the **IP-Adress** for your backend is correct (using `ipconfig` for instance)
2. Make sure that the endpoint "`api/facebookuser`" is correct
3. Make sure that the EMULATOR is in the **same network** (e.g. WLAN) than your computer (assuming that the backend is running on localhost)